# How can I check a function for having arguments without checking their values, using jest & enzyme in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test a react component where an `onClick` event listener is on the parent element `<Div>` passing `e.target` as an argument to the `onClick` function.

I tried simulating the click using `enzyme.simulate` and passing a mock function and a mock argument as following:

```
let wrapper, cellClick, e;
beforeEach(() => {
  cellClick = jest.fn();
  e = {
    target: "div"
  };
  wrapper = shallow(<Board onCellClick={cellClick} />);
});

afterEach(() => {
  cellClick.mockReset();
});

it("should call props.cellClick() whith e.target argument", () => {
    wrapper.simulate("click", e.target);
    expect(cellClick.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(e.target);
});
```

here is the react component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Div from "./styles";

const Board = props => {
  return (
    <Div onClick={e => props.onCellClick(e.target)}>
      <div id="board">
        <div className="square" data-square="0" />
        <div className="square" data-square="1" />
        <div className="square" data-square="2" />
        <div className="square" data-square="3" />
        <div className="square" data-square="4" />
        <div className="square" data-square="5" />
        <div className="square" data-square="6" />
        <div className="square" data-square="7" />
        <div className="square" data-square="8" />
      </div>
    </Div>
  );
};
Board.propTypes = {
  onCellClick: PropTypes.function
};
export default Board;
```

and here's the test results:

```
 Interaction with the board cells › should call props.cellClick() whith e.target argument

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "div"
    Received: undefined

      49 |   it("should call props.cellClick() whith e.target argument", () => {
      50 |     wrapper.simulate("click", e.target);
    > 51 |     expect(cellClick.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(e.target);
         |                                        ^
      52 |   });
      53 | });
      54 | 

      at Object.toBe (components/Board/Board.test.js:51:40)
```

I want the simulate method to simulate an actual click so it has an event object, which will then contain the child element as a target, without me using a mock object.
Or at least I want to test for the presence of an argument without checking its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're passing `e.target` to `wrapper.simulate`...

...just change that to `e` and it should work:

```
it("should call props.cellClick() whith e.target argument", () => {
  wrapper.simulate("click", e);  // <= pass e
  expect(cellClick.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(e.target);  // Success!
});
```

Comment: It's worked!, Thank you
But I can't understand why didn't it work when passing `e.target`

Comment: `onClick` is bound to this function `e => props.onCellClick(e.target)}` so the object used to simulate the event needs to have a `target` property so that the `target` property of the event can be passed to `props.onCellClick` @HassanNemir